# Message Attachments Array Problem | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

**Function:** To gather all message attachments in a channel and return their url.

**Code:**

```
const scrapemember = require('./Scraper/scraper.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "Scraper")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "Scraper", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")){
        Scrape(message);
        function Scrape (message) {
            const images = message.attachments.map((img) => img.url)
          if(!scrapemember[message.guild.name]) {
            scrapemember[message.guild.name] = {
              URL: images,
            }
        
          fs.writeFile('./Scraper/scraper.json', JSON.stringify(scrapemember, null, 2), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
          })
          message.delete()
        message.channel.send(`*Images Scraped*`)
        }
        }
      }
```

**Result: Inside `scraper.json`**

```
{
  "test (bot)": {
    "URL": []
  }
}
```

*I'm still not sure how to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated ;)*

**Edit:**

```
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")){
        Scrape(message);
        function Scrape (message) {
            const images = message.channel.messages.cache.map(img => img.url)
          if(!scrapemember[message.guild.name]) {
            scrapemember[message.guild.name] = {
              URL: images,
            }
        
          fs.writeFile('./Scraper/scraper.json', JSON.stringify(scrapemember, null, 2), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
          })
          message.delete()
        message.channel.send(`*Images Scraped*`)
        }
        }
      }
```

*So this time I used `.cache` in order to get an array of the messages but the result differs.*

**Second Result:**

```
{
  "test (bot)": {
    "URL": [
      "https://discord.com/channels/781240723277742151/791081666289729567/792138804969734185"
    ]
  }
}
```

*I'm guessing this is one of the images ID but in a form of a URL. Still quite puzzled*

**Edit #2**

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")){
        Scrape(message);
        function Scrape (message) {
            const URLs = message.channel.messages.fetch().then( msg => msg.map(links => links.attachments)).then(geturls => geturls.map( result => result.filter(final => final.url)))
          if(!scrapemember[message.guild.name]) {
            scrapemember[message.guild.name] = {
              URL: URLs,
            }
        
          fs.writeFile('./Scraper/scraper.json', JSON.stringify(scrapemember, null, 2), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
          })
          message.delete()
        message.channel.send(`*Images Scraped*`)
        }
        }
      }
```

*I realised I was requesting for a message and not an attachment and so I checked the [MessageManager Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager) and used the `.fetch()` method.*

*The code to keep an eye is this variable:*

```
const URLs = message.channel.messages.fetch().then( msg => msg.map(links => links.attachments)).then(geturls => geturls.map( result => result.filter(final => final.url)))
```

**Third Result:**

```
{
  "test (lovell)": {
    "URL": {}
  }
}
```

*Ive Tried the following:*

```
const URL3 = message.channel.messages.fetch().then( msg => msg.map(links => links.attachments)).then(geturls => geturls.map( result => result.filter(final => final.url).map( UrlLink => UrlLink.url)))
```

```
const URL2 = message.channel.messages.fetch().then( msg => msg.map(links => links.attachments)).then(geturls => geturls.map( result => result.filter(final => final.url).array()))
```

*They both replicate the same result.*

Comment: It's unclear what you expect as a result, how you intended to get to it and what is currently your problem. Be specific and help will rain like never before ;)

Comment: So the problem you're facing is that (as you said) you are trying to grab all of the attachments in the channel, but in your code, you are only trying to grab the attachments of the current message. I'm not 100% sure what code would work since you're using command syntax, but you would need to loop over all the messages in the channel instead of just one message in order to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: OHHHHH I see, thank you for pointing out what I did wrong, I'll try come up with a solution.

Comment: Would you look at my most recent edits and perhaps guide me into finding a solution